# Redirect folder to subdomain and another server

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, webserver

I have following situation:

```
www.domain.com/folder
```

and I want to redirect this folder to

```
www.subdomain.domain.com
```

And this subdomain is redirected via DNS to another IP/Server.

Is this possible, and how if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(folder(?:/.*|$))$ http://www.subdomain.domain.com/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Now, the redirect is working, but it goes to www.subdomain.domain.com/folder and it should only go to www.subdomain.domain.com